# How to catch Android View intent for calendar events?

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to be able to display my own calendar events, given an Android intent and a date to display. I believe that the intent to do so looks like this:

```
Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW act=content://com.android.calendar/time/1409565898789 }
```

And I have set up the Activity to handle this intent with an intent filter specified thus in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_custom"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- etc. -->
</activity>
```

In order to test this code, I load my application onto my test device and issue an intent using this command:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d content://com.android.calendar/time/1410665898789
```

But when I do so, the stock Android calendar is launched. I am never given an opportunity to view this time in another application. I think perhaps the Android system doesn't even recognize my Activity as a candidate for receiving this Intent.

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong and none of my searches have turned up the answer I'm seeking. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the scheme, MIME type, and perhaps the host to your `<intent-filter>`. Now, I do not know what the MIME type is precisely, so I am guessing that the following `<intent-filter>` from [the AOSP Calendar app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/) is what you are seeking:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="time/epoch" />
    <data android:host="com.android.calendar" />
    <data android:scheme="content"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Your current `<intent-filter>` will match nothing, unless some app has a bug and tries starting an `ACTION_VIEW` activity with no `Uri`.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I had been under the impression that for content: scheme data, I did not need to supply a <data> tag in my <intent-filter>. Thanks for setting me straight.